# How to detect when two images "collide"?

Tags: android, image, collision-detection, collision

I have two ImageViews, i am wondering if there is any way to write some sort of if statement that checks whether the two images "hit" each other, thanks.

Comment: Would this imply the ImageView(s) are in motion or can be moved with input?

Answer (score 1):

You can Do it by making two class of players

```
public class Player
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Width;
    int Height;
}

public class Enemy
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Width;
    int Height;
}
```

Then in gameloop use this code

```
foreach (Enemy e in EnemyCollection)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.X,e.Y,e.Width,e.Height);
    Rectangle p = new Rectangle(player.X,player.Y,player.Width,player.Height);

    // Assuming there is an intersect method, otherwise just handcompare the values
    if (r.Intersects(p))
    {
       // A Collision!
       // we know which enemy (e), so we can call e.DoCollision();
       e.DoCollision();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there no simpler way to check if they collide?

Comment: using the default coordinates of the image

Comment: just check the answer carefully and you will find your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample

```
Rect rc_img1 = new Rect();
 imageView1.getDrawingRect(rc_img1);

 Rect rc_img2 = new Rect();
 imageView2.getDrawingRect(rc_img2);

 if (Rect.intersects(rc_img1, rc_img2) {
   // intersection is detected
   // DO WHAT YOU WANT
 }
```

Comment: That does not seem  to be working with my animation on the first image